# Azure Search: Filtering terms with spaces, dashes and multiple terms

Tags: azure

I'm using the SDK for Azure Search and I have a requirement to filter terms that can contain spaces, dashes and multiple terms. For example, I have to filter based on last name. So, I need to filter names like Van Noy, Jackson-Davis, Jackson - Davis, and Jackson, Davis, Johnson, etc. Of course it should be able to handle any combination of these.

I started using search.in() and that handled the multiple terms (Jackson, Davis, Johnson) just fine as long as there were no spaces in the term. I tried search.ismatch() and that handled terms with spaces, but not my need to handle the multiple terms. And neither one handled dashes.

Is there a way to achieve this via the SDK? Any assistance is appreciated.